# trigger event, when 2 SpriteNodes are at the same position

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

I want to fire an function when to SpriteNodes are at the same position.
For that I created a helper method like this:

```
func checkPositions(){
    if taxiNode.position.x == passenger.position.x {
        print("same position")
    }
}
```

I trigger this function from within the update function of the SpriteKit Loop. I can see the Nodes being on the same position, but the print statement is never shown on the screen.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Or how would an similar approach look like, that helps me to find out, if these Nodes are at the same position?

I am helpful as always for any help...

Comment: i think position.y also compare

Comment: yes, I did this also, but this does not help either :-(

Answer (score 3):

When you compare two `CGFloat` you can use:

```
public func isEqual(to other: CGFloat) -> Bool
```

in other words you can do:

```
func checkPositions(){
    if taxiNode.position.x.isEqual(to: passenger.position.x) {
        print("same position")
    }
}
```

---

**Addition**:

If you want to compare two `CGPoint` there is also:

```
public func equalTo(_ point2: CGPoint) -> Bool
```

**Usage**:

```
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
let destination: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
if point.equalTo(destination) {
    print("same position")
}
```